# Style issues with b-collapse and css

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

what I am trying to do is modify the style of my `b-collapse` since by default it has a vertical style that I think and what I want is to give my menu a horizontal style

This is how I implement it:

```
<div style="background-color:white;">
          <b-collapse id="collapse-cat-lvl1-469">
            <div data-cat-acc="473" class="grid-item parent-lvl-2">
              <a class="link -1 grid-sty-1" href="#" target="_self" data-menu-item-id="473">
                <span class="text">GTI</span>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div data-cat-acc="474" class="grid-item parent-lvl-2">
              <a class="link sty-1 grid-sty-1" href="#" target="_self" data-menu-item-id="474">
                <span class="text">Pets</span>
              </a>
            </div>
         </b-collapse>
        </div>
```

You can modify `<b-collapse id = "collapse-cat-lvl1-469">` in if this: `collapse-cat-lvl1-469` ???

What I intend is to give it better style with CSS, or some way that I can see my menu horizontally and not vertically

```
    .navbar-greetings, .login-section{display: none}

      #menu-header.collapse:not(.show){
        display: block;
      }

      #menu-header{
        position: fixed;
        top: 25px;
        max-width: 83%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        left: 8.32%;
        .panel{
          button{
            display: block;
            color: white;
            font-size: 13px;
            font-family: 'VWHead-Bold';
          }
        }
        #accordion-mbl-menu{
          display: flex;
        }
      }
```

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproducible example using the code snippet tool

Comment: I don't know what's going on but the question is a duplicate question and had been asked by you @Inphyy : https://stackoverflow.com/q/67082483/6595551