# Modify style with b-collapse and css

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

what I am trying to do is modify the style of my `b-collapse` since by default it has a vertical style that I think and what I want is to give my menu a horizontal style

This is how I implement it:

```
<div style="background-color:white;">
      <b-collapse id="collapse-cat-lvl1-469">
        <div data-cat-acc="473" class="grid-item parent-lvl-2">
          <a class="link -1 grid-sty-1" href="#" target="_self" data-menu-item-id="473">
            <span class="text">GTI</span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div data-cat-acc="474" class="grid-item parent-lvl-2">
          <a class="link sty-1 grid-sty-1" href="#" target="_self" data-menu-item-id="474">
            <span class="text">Pets</span>
          </a>
        </div>
     </b-collapse>
    </div>
```

You can modify  in if this: collapse-cat-lvl1-469 ???

What I intend is to give it better style with CSS, or some way that I can see my menu horizontally and not vertically

I have this:

[image]

I want to get to this:

[image]

My CSS:

```
  .navbar-greetings, .login-section{display: none}

  #menu-header.collapse:not(.show){
    display: block;
  }

  #menu-header{
    position: fixed;
    top: 25px;
    max-width: 83%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 8.32%;
    .panel{
      button{
        display: block;
        color: white;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-family: 'VWHead-Bold';
      }
    }
    #accordion-mbl-menu{
      display: flex;
    }
  }
```

I am really new to this, searching the web I have not been able to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can do this by just `CSS` without using `b-collapse`, and maybe using `b-dropdown` is better than `b-collapse` but I understand your problem and make a code snippet.

Look at this solution and maybe it'll be useful for you.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
})
```

```css
.customHorizontalList {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.customHorizontalList>li {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
    <b-button v-b-toggle.collapse-1 variant="primary">Toggle Collapse</b-button>
  <b-collapse id="collapse-1" class="mt-2">
    <ul class="customHorizontalList">
      <li>ITEM 1</li>
      <li>ITEM 2</li>
      <li>ITEM 3</li>
    </ul>
  </b-collapse>
</div>
```

Comment: ok I just have a question, I have to add `'<link>, <script>` inside the tags: `<script type="application/javascript"> ...</script>`  ????   if I am working with Vue.JS

Comment: If you find it helpful, please consider accepting, thanks. @Inphyy

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: flex` on containing element

Comment: so I have it implemented

Comment: @Inphyy the first row is horizontal. Do the same.